# Searching on Google Appengine Datastore (Java)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have a "User" entity with the these properties: id, first_name, last_name, email, etc.

What's the best way to search for a full name? That combining first_name and last name of course. I couldn't find String-contains like query

Answer (score 1):

You could split the full name you want to search for into first name and last name, then perform a query [filtered](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#filters) with 2 equality checks on the 2 properties combined with an `AND` condition.

The exact syntax depends on the datastore library you use.

And you need to have a composite [index](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes) for that query.